# Changing forEach loop to for-loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, for-loop, foreach

I currently have a forEach loop like this.

```
var videoUrls ={};
ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(',')
.forEach(function(item) {
    var obj = { };
    item.split('&')
    .forEach(function(param) {
       param = param.split('=');
       obj[param[0]] = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);

});
videoUrls[obj.quality] = obj;});
```

Since IE is not supporting forEach loop, I tried to convert this to for loop.

```
var videoUrls ={};
var typea= ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(',');
for (var item=0; item<typea.length; item++){
   var obj= {};
   var typeb= typea[item].split('&');
   for (var param=0; param<typeb.length; param++){

       typeb[param]= typeb[param].split('=');
       obj[typeb[0]] = decodeURIComponent(typeb[1]);

}
videoUrls[obj.quality]= obj;
}
```

But when I run the script the results were different. What did i do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case, it might make sense to polyfill forEach for IE

Comment: You should take a look at this: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Comment: In this case, it might make sense to update IE to edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
typeb[param]= typeb[param].split('=');
obj[typeb[param][0]] = decodeURIComponent(typeb[param][1]);
```

Because the other loop is:

```
param = param.split('=');
obj[param[0]] = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
```

Not:

```
obj[item.split("&")[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item.split("&")[1])
```

If it's still not clear, here is a simpler explanation:

```
typeb === item.split("&");
typeb[param] === param;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should pay more attention to small details like this...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for (var param=0; param<typeb.length; param++) {
    typeb[param]= typeb[param].split('=');
    obj[typeb[0]] = decodeURIComponent(typeb[1]);
}
```

You're overwriting an element of the array you're iterating over (`typeb[param]`) and then using a hardcoded index into the same array (`typeb[1]`)

Should be more like:

```
for (var param=0; param<typeb.length; param++) {
    var arr = typeb[param].split('=');
    obj[arr[0]] = decodeURIComponent(arr[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And you cannot use library like jQuery? It is for this reason jQuery is built. If you cannot then i think this is what you need to do
obj[typeb[param][0]] = decodeURIComponent(typeb[param][1]);